# Python: How to get object's true length?

Tags: python, objects, dimensions

I need to calculate object's 'length factor', for example:

[image]
[image]

... To achieve this, I need to get object's true length:

[image: TrueLengthGoal]

... But the 'dimensions' vector contains dimensions of bounding box, so it's different when we e.g. rotate the object.
I have a code that will calculate the 'length factor' value, the only problem is that the 'dimensions' values are from bounding box, not from the object itself. Here's the code:

```
dimensions = list(ob.dimensions) 
maxDimension1 = max(dimensions)
dimensions.remove(maxDimension1)
maxDimension2 = max(dimensions)
lengthFactor = (maxDimension1/maxDimension2) - 1
```

I'd be grateful for some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance between two points can be calculated by extending the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle#Pythagorean_theorem) to [three dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42640). The x,y,z lengths you calculate as the distance between each point on the axis, then square those lengths and get the square root of the sum.

```
import bpy
from math import sqrt

loc1 = bpy.data.objects['Cube'].location
loc2 = bpy.data.objects['Cube.001'].location

xlen = loc1.x - loc2.x
ylen = loc1.y - loc2.y
zlen = loc1.z - loc2.z

dist = sqrt(xlen**2 + ylen**2 + zlen**2)
```

Which you can simplify down to -

```
def distance(p1, p2):
    return sqrt((p1[0]-p2[0])**2+(p1[1]-p2[1])**2+(p1[2]-p2[2])**2)
```

But that still leaves the dilema of choosing which verts you want to measure between. In your third example of a rotated rectangle, the min/max on y will give you the two outer points and by discarding the `min(x)` and `max(x)` you will get the two x locations of the y extremes, this can give you the diagonal length of the rectangle. Similarly if you use `min(y)` and discard `max(y)` the next `max(y)` will give you the longest edge.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below script to get the dimensions of the selected object:

```
x = bpy.context.object.dimensions[0]
y = bpy.context.object.dimensions[1]
z = bpy.context.object.dimensions[2]
```

which is controlled from the 3d view as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An objects bounding box is rotated when the object is rotated, so it is always in local coordinates. You can access them as follows

```
ob.bound_box[i][j]
```

Where `i` is the index of the bounding box corner vertex. Every bounding box is a cuboid and thus has 8 vertices. `j` is the coordinate of this point, 0 for x, 1 for y and 2 for z. So finding the bounding box length along local axes you could do

```
bb = ob.bound_box
dx_local = max(bb[i][0] for i in range(8)) - min(bb[i][0] for i in range(8))
dy_local = max(bb[i][1] for i in range(8)) - min(bb[i][1] for i in range(8))
dz_local = max(bb[i][2] for i in range(8)) - min(bb[i][2] for i in range(8))
longest_side = max(dx_local*ob.scale[0], dx_local*ob.scale[1], dx_local*ob.scale[2])
```

However, I cannot quit figure out how you define the "scalefactor". I guess you can do the rest yourself.

Comment: ... The longest_side value changes after applying rotation though. Is there a way to fix it? By the way, I've found a way to get the second longest side, like that: https://pastebin.com/2XWRNcJD

Comment: After some testing, it looks like it shows the same value as the regular '.dimensions' value... Do I miss something?

Comment: The bounding box does rotate with the object, however it doesn't match the mesh if the mesh is rotated in edit mode. [See this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAMVX.jpg) of a single flat triangle.

Answer (score 0):

A bit simplified and more elegant version of sambler's answer:

```py
    import bpy
    loc1 = bpy.data.objects['Cube'].location
    loc2 = bpy.data.objects['Cube.001'].location
    dist = (loc1 - loc2).length
```