# Trigonometry in blender

Tags: python

Please help me find the length between two dots with Blender api. That value will be the sine.  After that I need to find cassettes of the triangle I'll get.

[image]

Thank.

Comment: The [Pythagorean theorem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/77731/935) works in three dimensions.

Comment: I need to find the cassettes and not the hypotenuse

Comment: Are the red lines always in the direction of the global axes? Are the blue points always in the yz plane? I assume you have the coordinates of the two blue points stored as Vectors, is this correct? Is there something about the grid mesh interesting for the problem?

Comment: The points are the vectors, the coordinates of the vertices. Vertices can be in any planes. Red lines can be in any field, the only constant is their angle of 90 degrees

Comment: Your problem is still not accurately described. If the points (p1 and p2) are not in a certain plane then no unique right triangle exists. But in the case they are: the cathetus is just the difference of the z coordiantes or the difference of the y coordinates, e.g. Vector([0,p1.y-p2.y,0].

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by [cassette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassette) me thinks  @Dimali on track with [cathetus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathetus) 2 points only define a line.  Need 3 points to define a plane. Will need another point, or another direction vector like say the z axis `Vector((0, 0, 1))`  in which case your vector `v = p2 - p1` and the z axis cross with angle `v.angle(z_axis)` and the cathetus will be sin and cos of this angle times `v.length`.